# How do I pass a variable to mySQL without using the query module?

Tags: templates, php, sql

I can echo the current `entry_id` but when I try to pass that variable to a mySQL statement, it doesn't work.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="test" entry_id="20"}
  <?php
  $entry_id = '{entry_id}';
  echo $entry_id; // returns 20

  $sql_query = "SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE entry_id = $entry_id"; // doesn't work
  $sql_query = "SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE entry_id = 20"; // this works

  // rest of code
  ?> 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would work with any of "PHP Parsing Stage" of template preference. You can use Query module tag instead of using PHP code with channel entry tag like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="test" entry_id="20"}

{exp:query sql="SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}'" parse="inward"}
{col1}
{/exp:query}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It would work for you.

*** Edited *****
In the case, it's necessary for you to have PHP code within the template you can embed a template within it like:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="test" entry_id="20"}

{embed="temp_grp/embedded_temp" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

and you can have PHP code within the template like:

```
  <?php
  $entry_id = "{embed:entry_id}";

  $sql_query = "SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE entry_id = $entry_id";

  // rest of code
  ?>
```

Don't forget setting the "PHP Parsing Stage" as "Output" in template preferences with "Allow PHP"

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way of doing it without the query module?

Comment: Yes, you can embed another template and put the PHP code within that and pass entry_id as embed variable like: {embed="temp_group/temp_name" entry_id="{entry_id}"} and you can use {embed:entry_id} within "temp_group/temp_name" and use $entry_id = '{embed:entry_id}'; with further coding. Do not forget setting the "PHP Parsing Stage" as "Output" in template preferences with "Allow PHP".

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. Can you edit that into your answer? Regards.

Comment: Glad, it worked for you. I edited my answer.